# My android project works but when adding breakpoint it doesn't

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I have an androidn app in eclips.
it works when i debbug without any break points
but if i add a break poing it dosent work black screen on the emulator
after remove break point it works again.

EDIT:
when i delete .metadata folder it Works at the end

Comment: So you set a breakpoint at an early state of your App, making it break before it even started up completly. But whats your question?

Comment: you dont understan my question it works witout any break point bu if i add break point it dosent work that is all

Comment: without read my question marked my -1

Comment: This is perfectly normal. Breakpoints can stop an application from working.

Comment: but i dosent stop i freez and do nathing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had same problem then i installed android sutudio. eclipse and android sutudio are wanting

Answer (score 0):

The execution pauses when it reaches the breakpoint. The IDE usually shows you the line where the execution paused...

[image: Line where execution paused]

...and is waiting for you to press a button to resume it.

[image: Button to resume execution]

Comment: i know how the debbuger works. but my problem if i add any break point by emulator freez an do nathing

Comment: My bad. Post the code around the breakpoint.

Comment: public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
 {
  switch (item.getItemId())
     {
      case R.id.menuTazele:
       LoadPage(); // break point is hear      
       return true;

Comment: And this activity does not even load, it goes straight to black screen and stays? Do you see any message like "Waiting for debuggger to attach"? Maybe try different emulator. Recently I've had good experience using Genymotion.